# Expressing A number in the Form of Three Squares

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, square, number-theory

I am giving `Q` query , in each query i am given a number `N` , i have to output three integer such that sum of square of three integer equals to `N`

```
For Ex:
3
5
13
Ans:
1,1,1  (1^2+1^2+1^2)
2,1,0  (2^2+1^2+0^2)
3 2 0  (3^2+2^2+0^2)
```

My Approach:
[Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_three-square_theorem)

```
  Solution(Num):

    if Num in form 4^a*(8b+7) return No

   for(i=Math.sqrt(Num);j>=0;j--){
            Rem = Num-j*j;
    for(k=Math.sqrt(Rem);k>=0;k--){

               Rem2 = Rem-k*k;
               double X = Math.sqrt(Rem2);
               if(X==(long)X) return Found

    }
```

But My Solution is giving me `TLE` , Since  `N` is upto `10^15` and `Q` is upto `10^5` , how can i improve my solution ? Can i do some sort of preprocessing ?

For `N` less than 10^6 , i can give answer in `O(1)` time by preprocessing , but how to handle the large numbers.

Comment: Answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104322/efficient-computation-of-integer-representation-as-sum-of-three-squares